# form validation sometimes not working in laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, validation, eloquent

i want to apply validation to the file input only if its visible. i have applied `sometimes` laravel form validation but it's not working. Here i have showed my code below:

```
<div class="d-none col-sm-6 attach_doc_div">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="hidden" name="is_file_visible" id="is_file_visible">
        <input type="file" name="attach_doc" class="form-control" id="attach_doc">
        <span class="text-info">Please attach the deposit slip or screenshot after submitting the fee to <a href="#" class="text-danger acc_detail">account details</a></span>
        @error('attach_doc')
            <br><span class="text-danger"> {{ $message }} </span>
        @enderror
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the Jquery part for setting value of hidden field with `id=is_file_visible` true or false

```
$('select[name=payment_option]').on('change', function() {
    var payment_option_check = $('select[name=payment_option] :selected').val();
    if (payment_option_check == 1) {
        $('.attach_doc_div').removeClass('d-none');
        $('#is_file_visible').val(true);
    } else {
        $('.attach_doc_div').addClass('d-none');
        $('#is_file_visible').val(false);
    }
});
```

Here is hthe form validation on controller side

```
$request->validate([
    'attach_doc'=> 'sometimes | required | required_if:is_file_visible,true | file'
]);
```

Comment: so what about it "is not working"? also why did you add all those random spaces to the validation rules string?

Comment: What about `'attach_doc' => ['file', 'required_if:is_file_visible,true']`

Comment: @lagbox I added spaces to make it more readable, the problem i am having is this valdiation is not working for me, form is still submitting without attach_doc file.

Answer (score 0):

Write like this:

```php
$request->validate([
    'attach_doc'=> 'sometimes|required_if:is_file_visible,true|file'
]);
```

Comment: didn't work, tried it as well.